# phpmyadmin only showing source code

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am trying to develop my own website on a ubuntu 16.04 machine with php7.

I have got everything working including php7, apache2, mysql but when I got to the installation of phpmyadmin, I hit a roadbump and was doing alot of googling and tried tons of suggestions I found but I still failed to get the installation complete.

After I did apt-get install phpmyadmin, the package got installed but when I went to 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/ I only see the source code.

I made sure I had all the extensions I needed and I also made sure php is running correctly on apache by doing a classic php.info()

P.S. I am installing from scratch and not doing and upgrade from an old system.

Many thanks!

[source code for phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbQRa.png)

Comment: `php.info()` is a typo?

Comment: You have phpmyadmin set as symlink ?
Maybe your apache cant load php on symlinks.
Check your apache config.